# My returned array is not returning as an object

Tags: php, ajax, json, pdo

My returned array is coming back in this strange format that is not valid. At least not in my AJAX experience.

```
function get_within($latitude, $longitude) { 
global $pdo;

  // $lat = $latitude;
  // $long = $longitude;
  // $long = '-70.98245279999999';
  // $lat = '41.98156549999999';

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT menu_id, latitude, longitude ( acos(
          cos( radians(".$latitude."   ) ) *
            cos( radians( latitude) ) * 
            cos( radians(".$longitude.") - radians(longitude)) +
            sin( radians(".$latitude.") ) * sin( radians(latitude) ) ))*.621371192
as dis from pages where 1 ORDER BY `dis` ASC LIMIT 10");

$stmt->execute( array() );

return $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_OBJ );
```

I made an AJAX request using the above function. I need it to return an object but it is only returning an array like this:

> `[{"id":"26","subject_id":"5","menu_name":"Bobby Byrne's Food & Pub\u200e","position":"1","visible":"1","content":"Bobby Byrne's Restaurant & Pub\u200e\r\n65 Massachusetts 6A, Sandwich, MA\r\n(508) 888-6088","longitude":"-70.508598","latitude":" 41.765754","dis":"0.00245126419033985"}]`

What is wrong and how can I get back my query in objects correctly for use?

Comment: I guess you `echo json_encode(get_within(x, y));`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response is a JSON encoded object. You need to decode the JSON to an object.

Please see:
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php

Answer (score 0):

As @DanArmstrong points out there's nothing strange or invalid about the JSON array being returned. [Per the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) `PDOStatement::fetchAll` is supposed to return an array—which it is—and when you encode an array as JSON it uses [array notation](http://www.json.org/), which is valid JSON and what you're seeing here.

If you want a JSON object instead of the array you need to either:

1. On the server side get an item out of the array returned by `fetchAll` and encode that
   value (e.g. `json_encode( $results[0] )`) instead of encoding the entire returned
   array, or
2. On the client side get an item out of the decoded array e.g. `JSON.parse( data )[0]`.

Comment: Ah! That's it! The only thing now is I can't figure out how to get all 10 results from the object. $locations = json_encode($results[0]); gives me the first object. How can I get them all? Some type of loop through?